# Read text data from file using LINQ

Tags: c#, linq, text

I have following text file:

```
37 44 60
67 15 94
45 02 44
```

How to read all numbers from this file and save them into two-dimensional array, using LINQ? All I manged to do was creating a simple array with all first values in each row. Is using LINQ in this case a good idea or should I simply load the file normal way and parse it?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

```
File.ReadAllLines(myFile)
    .Select(l => l.Split(' ').Select(int.Parse).ToArray()).ToArray();
```

Or:

```
List<int[]> forThoseWhoHave1GigFiles = new List<int[]>();
using(StreamReader reader = File.OpenText(myFile))
{
    while(!reader.EndOfStream)
    {
        string line = reader.ReadLine();
        forThoseWhoHave1GigFiles.Add(line.Split(' ')
            .Select(int.Parse).ToArray());
    }
}
var myArray = forThoseWhoHave1GigFiles.ToArray();
```

And:

```
File.ReadLines(myFile)
    .Select(l => l.Split(' ')
    .Select(int.Parse).ToArray())
    .ToArray();
```

In .Net 4.0 and above.

Comment: ReadAllLines loads all lines into memory... what if the file weighs 1GB ?

Comment: Elegant!  Except, you may want a second .ToArray() on the end to be able to assign it directly to a jagged array int[][].

Comment: @Jesse: yes, both of my methods unfortunately assign it to a jagged array instead of [,].

Comment: A better solution than either of the proposed answers above is to use [File.ReadLines(filename)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd383503.aspx) which streams the file and is therefore going to be much more memory efficient when reading large files. Aesthetically it's more pleasing too as it allows you to also stay purely in LINQ instead of that hybrid 2nd option.

Comment: @JTR That may be for .Net 4.0+, but when I answered the question, it wasn't released yet.

Comment: @Yuriy Fair enough, you did have valid solutions at the time you wrote, but my comment still stands as of today.

Answer (score 5):

Just to complete Jonathan's answer, here's how you could implement the `Lines` extension method :

```
public static class TextReaderExtensions
{
    public static IEnumerable<string> Lines(this TextReader reader)
    {
        string line;
        while((line = reader.ReadLine()) != null) yield return line;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Do you mean something like this?

```
StreamReader sr = new StreamReader("./files/someFile.txt");

      var t1 =
        from line in sr.Lines()
        let items = line.Split(' ')
        where ! line.StartsWith("#")
        select String.Format("{0}{1}{2}",
            items[1],
            items[2],
            items[3]);
```

Take a look to this web: [LINK](http://www.onedotnetway.com/tutorial-reading-a-text-file-using-linq/)

Comment: you'd better split on a space since it's not comma delimited.

Comment: There's no StreamReader.Lines() method... but it would be easy to create an extension method that enumerates all lines in the StreamReader